# Как сделать несколько перечислений с одинаковыми методами, но с разными наборами значений?

Tags: java, методы

Мне нужно несколько перечислений, имеющих одинаковые поля, конструкторы и методы, но разные наборы значений. Я знаю, что перечисления нельзя наследовать в лоб, но не знает ли кто-нибудь способа эмулировать что-нибудь примерно вот такое:

```
  enum Parent {
    DUMMY_ITEM("", 0);

    String otherName;
    int intValue;

    Parent(String otherName, int intValue) {
      this.intValue = intValue;
      this.otherName = otherName; 
    } 

    void setIntValue(int value) { intValue = value; }
    int getIntValue()           { return intValue; }
    int calcSomething()         { return intValue * otherName.length(); }
  }

  enum Child1 extends Parent {
    ACTUAL_CHILD1_ITEM1("CHILD1_ITEM1", 1),
    ACTUAL_CHILD1_ITEM2("CHILD1_ITEM2", 1),
    ACTUAL_CHILD1_ITEM3("CHILD1_ITEM3", 1),
  }  

  enum Child2 extends Parent {
    ACTUAL_CHILD2_ITEM1("CHILD2_ITEM1", 1),
    ACTUAL_CHILD2_ITEM2("CHILD2_ITEM2", 1),
    ACTUAL_CHILD2_ITEM3("CHILD2_ITEM3", 1),
  }
```

Чтобы можно было писать `int i = ACTUAL_CHILD2_ITEM1.getIntValue()`, `int j = ACTUAL_CHILD1_ITEM3.calcSomething()` и т. п. Некрасиво повторять много раз один и тот же код методов и все поля в разных перечислениях, но при этом очень хочется использовать разные наборы значений, чтобы они не путались, и чтобы IDE подсказывала правильные имена констант.

Comment: Разве что использовать интерфейсы. Либо что-то еще из предложенного тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650045/how-to-enable-enum-inheritance

Comment: @selya как тут можно выкрутиться с интерфейсами? -- я об этом думал, но ничего придумать не смог.

Comment: Напишу в виде ответа, как можно выкрутиться, заменив enum на class

Comment: Заголовки методов, конечно, можно вынести в интерфейс, но смысла большого я этом не вижу -- поля в интерфейсе иметь нельзя, значит их надо описывать в перечислениях, тогда и реализацию методов все равно придется повторять 10 раз, в каждом перечислении по-отдельности

Comment: @m.vokhm зачем реализацию методов повторять?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в интерфейсах нет полей, значит придется повторить реализацию метода в каждом enum, в котором вы добавите поля (если метод должен тянуть поле, к примеру - `getValue()`)

Comment: @selya только геттера для этого поля. Методы с основной логикой повторять не нужно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev А основная логика обычно тоже читает поля))

Comment: @selya если нарушать архитектурные принципы, то да. Правильно обращаться к данным только через геттеры и сеттеры.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev они должны иметь доступ к полям. Получать в моем случае все поля через геттеры -- возможно, но громоздко и некрасиво.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Зачем мне обращаться через геттеры и сеттеры к полям внутри?) Это мало того, что затратно, ибо вызывается функция, так еще и громоздко

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, архитектурные принципы хороши там, где они уместны. Не надо делать из них догму.

Comment: @selya Джошуа Блох в "Effective java" пишет об этом более развёрнуто и доходчиво, чем я смог бы написать в комментариях.

Answer (score 1):

[Методы по умолчанию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) спасут отца русской демократии:

```
interface ArithmeticEnum {
    String getOperation();

    default int apply(int x, int y) {
        switch (getOperation()) {
            case "+":
                return x + y;
            case "-":
                return x - y;
            case "*":
                return x * y;
            case "/":
                return x / y;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknow operation!");
        }
    }
}

public enum BasicOperations implements ArithmeticEnum {
    PLUS("+"),
    MINUS("-"),
    TIMES("*"),
    DIVIDE("/");

    private final String symbol;

    public BasicOperations(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getOperation() {
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну тоже в принципе вариант, но в моем случае это, кажется, получится слишком громоздко. Но я подумаю в этом направлении, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно выкрутиться через классы:

```
public abstract class E {                                     // базовый enum
    public final int intValue;
    public final String stringValue;

    protected E(int intValue, String stringValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public void printValues() {
        System.out.println(intValue + " " + stringValue);
    }
}


public class EChild extends E {                              // наследуемый enum
    private EChild(int intValue, String stringValue) {
        super(intValue, stringValue);
    }

    public static EChild ENUM_1 = new EChild(1, "someString");
    public static EChild ENUM_2 = new EChild(2, "otherValue");
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EChild e = EChild.ENUM_1;

        System.out.println(e == EChild.ENUM_1); // true
        e.printValues(); // 1 someString
    }
}
```

Помечаем базовый как `abstract`, иначе модификатор `protected` на конструкторе даст нам создать экземпляр класса из любого класса в этом же `package`. В дочернем классе помечаем конструктор как `private`, чтобы не дать создавать экземпляры из-вне.

Comment: Да! Не так изящно, как хотелось бы, но да, это вариант, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях на английском StackOverflow подсказали *(и как сам-то не сообразил???)* простой вариант, котрый ближе всего к тому, что я хочу получить: в каждом элементе перечисления просто содержится объект, который инкапсулирует все данные и всю функциональность. Вот код, иллюстрирующий принцип:

```
  public class Test_enums {

    // Класс объектов, содержащих данные и методы:
    static class EnumData { 
      int intValue;
      String stringValue;

      EnumData(int intValue, String stringValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue; 
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
      }

      void setNewString(String s) { this.stringValue = s; }
      public String toString() { return intValue + ": " + stringValue; }
      int calcSomething() { return intValue * stringValue.length(); }
      // Anything else...
    }

    enum Enum1 {
      ENUM1_ITEM1(1, "Раз"),
      ENUM1_ITEM2(2, "Два");
      public EnumData data;
      Enum1(int intValue, String stringValue) {
        data = new EnumData(intValue, stringValue);
      }
    }

    enum Enum2 {
      ANOTHER_ENUM_ITEM1(1, "One"),
      ANOTHER_ENUM_ITEM2(2, "Two");
      EnumData data;
      Enum2(int intValue, String stringValue) {
        data = new EnumData(intValue, stringValue);
      } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Enum1.ENUM1_ITEM1.data);
      System.out.println(Enum1.ENUM1_ITEM2.data);
      System.out.println(Enum2.ANOTHER_ENUM_ITEM1.data);
      System.out.println(Enum2.ANOTHER_ENUM_ITEM2.data);
    }
  }
```